# Python mysql.connector - cursor.execute("WHERE .... ) returns NoneType

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I wanna code a login page using flask, but the value of the users that I get out of my database always is a NoneType. Even if the username that's entered in the login form is the same as the one in the database. I think I might have an error in the SQL Query but I can't figure Out where it is. I appreciate your help!

Here's the login function with the line that should return how many rows have been found in the database.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #get form fields
        username = request.form["username"]
        password_candidate = request.form["password"]

        result = sqlhandler.mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
        print(result) #result is a NoneType
```

here's the class of the sqlhandler:

```
class mySQLHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="notrealpassword ;)",
            db="testdb"
        )

        self.mycursor = self.db.cursor()
```

I'd really appreciate it, if anyone could tell me, why the execute statement returns a NoneType. I've already checked if the code in the mycursor.execute() works in the MySQL workbench and it does.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query execution and fetching divided into two separate steps. Get the data from your cursor after you execute the query:

```
sqlhandler.mycursor.execute("""
    SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE username = %s
""", [username])

data = sqlhandler.mycursor.fetchone()
print(data)
```

Reference:

- [`cursor.execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)
- [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)